# How to set launch file arguments using roslaunch Python API

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the roslaunch Python API to run some launch files. Some of these launch files have some arguments (specified with the `arg` tag). On the terminal, I would set these arguments like this:

```
roslaunch mypkg foobar.launch bla:=42
```

Unfortunately I am not able to figure out how to set the argument (`bla:=42`) when running the same launch file with the Python API.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272059/how-to-set-launch-file-arguments-using-roslaunch-python-api/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After digging for a while, I believe it's not possible to set the arguments using the API.

There are related questions in this forum and seems that the users are using python subprocess to do that:

https://answers.ros.org/question/198910/how-to-set-args-with-python-roslaunch/
https://answers.ros.org/question/265796/parameters-roslaunch-from-python-script/

There's a page in ROS wiki as example, but without arguments:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage

If you want to check by yourself, here goes the API page that refers to the launch object used in a ROS wiki:

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roslaunch/html/roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent-class.html

Fortunately, there's a Pull Request that proposes a solution to that issue:

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1115

I hope it can help you!

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2017-10-04**:
Thanks for linking the pull request, I did not find that one.

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-05-30**:
Update: The linked pull request is merged for lunar (not backported to previous versions, though)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As marcoarruda already wrote, there does not seem to be an option for this in the current API.

I checked the code of the `roslaunch` executable and found out, that they directly read the values from `sys.argv`. So a not very nice but working hack is to add arguments there before using roslaunch:

```
sys.argv.append("bla:=42")
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2